# Verifying signature of plaintext using encrypted message only

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, authenticated-encryption

I'm looking for an algorithm which allows verifying a signature of a plaintext message but while only having the encrypted message.

The requirement is for Alice to send Bob a plaintext message (M) which is signed (S) by central authority (CA), the message should be encrypted (E) to Bob.

Anyone should be able to verify (V) that each of the encrypted messages (E) matches its signature (S).

CA = Central authority signing plaintext messages

M = Plaintext message

S = Signature of M by CA

E = Encryption of M

V = Function validating S against E. V(E,S) is in {true,false}

Comment: Can you not just sign the ciphertext?

Comment: No. That will require me to go to the CA every time I want to send the same information. I want to go to the CA once with specific information and then just send it to different people.

Comment: In fact, the information is my identity, so I get it once from the CA signed and then sending it to different users on the network.

Comment: Why does the signature need to be unencrypted and verified by a protocol party with only the ciphertext?

Comment: Do you want to delegate your identity or prove your identity to someone? Why do you have a CA at all?

Comment: Note that any such feature of the encryption system would immediately render the encryption system insecure under standard definitions, because you can just guess a message and test whether this message verifies under the given CA public key and signature.

Comment: @SEJPM the message has a nonce to prevent guessing the message.

Comment: @cypherfox I want to prove my identity to someone specific while everybody else can see that I have an identity but cannot see what it is. The CA is the entity that issues the identity.

Comment: @somdoron this sounds poorly designed. You don't need the CA, nor even signatures for proofs of identities. Use keys as identities (ECDH) and then make any identity lookups (name to key) like DNS an orthogonal feature. Now you can use DNS (tree) or referral (graph), similar to pgp's web of trust, but without leaking the social graph or irrevokable signatures.

Comment: I'm also thinking in the direction of polymorphic ID's or attribute based crypto, but I think neither of those directly would deliver the required functionality. Possibly voting systems could also be of interest, where a voter must remain anonymous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a "signature-friendly" encryption scheme, where one can verify a signature on an encrypted message. We can define it as follows:

- KeyGen: generate keys $(\mathsf{pk},\mathsf{sk})$
- Encrypt: given $\mathsf{pk}$, a message $m$, and a signature $s$, output a ciphertext $c$
- Decrypt: given $\mathsf{sk}$, and a ciphertext $c$, output a plaintext $m$
- Verify: given $\mathsf{pk}$, a ciphertext $c$, and a signature $s$, output a bit $b$

With the following (informal) guarantees: (KeyGen,Encrypt,Decrypt) is one-way (as pointed out by SEJPM in the comments to the question, the scheme cannot be IND-CPA secure), encryption/decryption work correctly, and Verify($\mathsf{pk},c,s$) outputs 1 if and only if Check(Decrypt($c,\mathsf{sk}$),$s)=1$, where Check is the signature verification algorithm.

We can build such an encryption scheme in a natural way, starting from any encryption scheme, any signature scheme, and a non-interactive zero-knowledge (NIZK) proof system. A NIZK proof system for a language $L$ works as follows:

- Setup: generate a common reference string crs
- Prove: given a word $x$ and a witness $w$ for $x\in L$ (and the crs), output a proof $\pi$ of $x\in L$
- Verify: given a word $x$ and a proof $\pi$ (and the crs), output a bit

with the following guarantees: if the prover is honest (and $x\in L$), Verify outputs 1, if $x\notin L$, no prover can construct a proof $\pi$ accepted by Verify, and the proof leaks no information about $w$ (slightly more formally, the proof can be *simulated* without $w$).

Let $E$ denote some arbitrary encryption scheme, and $S$ denote some arbitrary signature scheme. Consider a NIZK proof system for the language $L$ of triples $(\mathsf{pk},c,s)$ such that $c$ is an encryption with $\mathsf{pk}$ (under $E$) of a message $m$ satisfying Check$(m,s)=1$ (where Check is the signature verification algorithm of $S$). The witness for $(\mathsf{pk},c,s)\in L$ is the pair $(m,r)$ such that $c=$Encrypt$(\mathsf{pk},m;r)$ and Check$(m,s)=1$.

- KeyGen: generates keys $(\mathsf{pk},\mathsf{sk})$ for $E$, and a common reference string crs for the NIZK proof system. The public key is $(\mathsf{pk},$crs$)$ an the secret key is $\mathsf{sk}$.
- Encrypt: given $(\mathsf{pk}$,crs$)$, a message $m$, and a signature $s$, check that Check$(m,s)=1$; output $\bot$ if this is not the case. Else, compute an encryption $c$ of $m$ under $E$ with $\mathsf{pk}$ (with a random coin $r$), and a proof $\pi$ of $(\mathsf{pk},c,s)\in L$, using witness $(m,r)$. Output the ciphertext $(c,\pi)$.
- Decrypt: given a ciphertext $(c,\pi)$ and $\mathsf{sk}$, output the decryption of $c$ under $E$ with $\mathsf{sk}$.
- Verify: given the public key $(\mathsf{pk}$,crs$)$, a ciphertext $(c,\pi)$, and a signature $s$, output NIZK.Verify(crs,$(\mathsf{pk},c,s), \pi$).

The security properties of the above scheme follow immediately from those of $E$ and from the zero-knowledge property of the NIZK proof system, and the signature verification property follows from the soundness of the NIZK proof system.

The above scheme is a somewhat generic template; to get an efficient construction, one must carefully choose the underlying primitives, with proof-friendly encryption scheme and signature scheme. To obtain better efficiency, it would probably be wise to use an interactive zero-knowledge proof, and to make it non-interactive in the random oracle model using the Fiat-Shamir transform. It requires some work, but it should be feasible to make this quite efficient with appropriate choice of the underlying primitives.